# ¿Como aplicar color a Bootstrap popover usando jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una tabla en la cual dentro de una de sus celdas tengo una etiqueta `"a"` a la cual deseo mostrar un popover al pasar el cursor del mouse:

```
    <table id="tableOcMateriales" class="ctrlLineTable table table-condensed  table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables_length" style="width: 100%; align-content: center">
    <thead class="ColorHeaderTable">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
            </th>
            <th style="display: none"></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="celda">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
                </td>
                <td style="display: none">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrdenCompraDetalleId)
                </td>
                <td class="celda" style="width: 20%">

                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Comentarios))
                    {
                        <a style='text-decoration: none;' href='#' id='turnonoff-@item.OrdenCompraDetalleId' title=''>
                            <i class='fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg' aria-hidden="true" style='color: #daa520'> </i>
                        </a>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Para agregar el popover me valgo de jquery:

```
    function changueTurnOffClass(ordenCompraDetalleId, turn, comentarios) {
    if (turn) {
        $("#turnonoff-" + ordenCompraDetalleId).find('i').removeClass("fa-toggle-on").addClass("fa-toggle-off").css('color', '#daa520').prop('title', '');
        $("#turnonoff-" + ordenCompraDetalleId).prop('title', '').attr("data-toggle", "popover").attr('data-placement', 'left').attr('data-trigger', 'hover').attr('data-content', comentarios).attr('data-original-title', '');
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    }
    else {
        $("#turnonoff-" + ordenCompraDetalleId).find('i').removeClass("fa-toggle-off").addClass("fa-toggle-on").css('color', '#008000').prop('title', 'Excluir de la Orden de compra');
    }
};
```

Para darle estilo al Popover utilizo este código en un archivo css:

```
    .popover {
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
    border-color: #004881;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.popover-content {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.popover.left .arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #f0ad4e;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, solo se aplica el estilo al Arrow pero no al `background`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando en archivo CSS, color de fondo al `popover-title` y `popover-content`.

Por ejemplo:

```
.popover-title,
.popover-content {
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}
```

Mas info sobre la declaración [`!important` aquí](http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/declaracion-important-css.html)

Comment: Hola: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo intente pero no sucede nada , el popover sigue mostrándose en gris cuando inserto los atributos por medio de jquery...

Comment: Hola: Gracias nuevamente, acabo de darme cuenta que el problema lo genera un bootstrap modal, antes de mostrar el modal los popovers se ven bien, después de mostrar el modal y cerrarlo, todos los popovers pierden el background-color del content...

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono al cambiar el 'background-color' por **backgroud:#f0ad4e!important**